# How to merge two git commiters into a single GitLab account?

Tags: git, gitlab

At my company we switched to GitLab, and we ran into the situation that for some people, spelling and/or emails changed - some people used both their work and their private emails for commits, while others used real or expanded Umlaute in their name (Joerg vs Jörg for example). Yet others were unfortunate enough to do both (me). Finally, some old commits were done in SVN and now show up with the users SVN username (which we unfortunately only discovered very late).

Is there any way to tell GitLab that these commits come from the same person ?

Comment: Git uses [the `.mailmap` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors), GitLab "should" use that but I can't tell from my googling whether it does yet, have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't :(